# Fujitsu D2616 Raid Card Lsi Mega Raid Enable Ports

Tags: raid, sas, sata, megaraid

I have a Fujitsu server with D2616 raid contorller, this has 2 mini SAS ports on it with one connecting into a backpane where i have 4 hdd plugged in. This works fine however wanted some SSD's in there and this card says in specs it has 8 ports so figured i would buy one of these:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Cable-Matters-Internal-SFF-8087-Breakout/dp/B07QFSLP6F/ref=pd_lpo_23_t_1/260-3015938-9732447?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07QFSLP6F&pd_rd_r=fbce699c-dcce-4d1c-aa1b-141e2ea73d2f&pd_rd_w=pkWvQ&pd_rd_wg=ZO8F3&pf_rd_p=7b8e3b03-1439-4489-abd4-4a138cf4eca6&pf_rd_r=03F4KM42ZPC0MXMJVNXK&psc=1&refRID=03F4KM42ZPC0MXMJVNXK

I connected this up all fine however no more drives seem to show in the raid controller. I have scanned through the BIOS and not seen anything that stood out to enable this next port.

Does this second port even work, or is this cable wrong not quite sure how to get it working properly and hoping for a nudge in the right direction?

There is also an advanced function however looks like it needs some licence so hope its not included in there. Can't seem to find any information online about this!

Answer (score 0):

I have 6 drives working in My Fujitsi RX200 S7 but I did that by using the disk backplane from another Fujitsu server that could accommodate 6 drives.

My controller was a DS2607 but that just gave me raid 1 so I bought a DS2616 from Ebay. Now I have a raid 5 array but ESXi 6.7 does not see any drives. Most disappointing.

I see you are using a D2616 what raid level did you use and what version of ESXi?